# how to capture image from webcam using Agora and Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, agora.io

I am trying to build a zoom website and take attendance from participants video streams. I am using Agora with react.js. Now, I am trying to capture images from video streams but I don't know how to do it with agora.
This is my function for capturing images.

```
const captureSnapshot = async () => {
    if (tracks[1]) {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = tracks[1].videoWidth;
      canvas.height = tracks[1].videoHeight;
      canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(tracks[1], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = dataUrl;
      link.download = "snapshot.png";
      link.click();
    }
```

This is where I'm getting tracks it holds audio and video tracks

```
const { ready, tracks } = useMicrophoneAndCameraTracks();
```

I found examples from agora documentations which should be something like this

```
const stream = tracks[1].captureStream(0)
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].requestFrame();
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

if you are using version 4.1.0 or higher, maybe try to get from channelParams.remoteVideoTrack frame data by using getCurrentFrameData(): ImageData; method

```
//something like this

const image = channelParams.remoteVideoTrack.getCurrentFrameData();
```

[screenshot from agora web example https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6atrY.png)

[screenshot from ILocalTrack interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGUeb.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)